# EBS Lifecycle Manager not taking snapshots

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am having trouble with the EBS Lifecycle Manager.

I have a simple EC2 environment: 1 EC2 with a single 50 GB volume attached to it.
I created an EBS Lifecycle Manager policy to snapshot the EC2's volume every 12 hours.
This seemed straightforward except it's not taking snapshots. There is no error or anything like that. Just no snapshots.

I've poked around and saw several posts with similar issues, but their solutions are not working.

I am using the default IAM role (AWSDataLifecycleManagerDefaultRole), and I do not believe I am using any conflicting tags.

Since there is no error or message, I do not know where to begin to troubleshoot this.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this? Maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The Lifecycle manager's schedule is set in UTC timezone. So make sure you are checking in the correct time. Also note that the minimum precision for schedules is 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitations you need to follow while creating a lifecycle manager for your EBS,

https://blog.searce.com/how-to-automate-aws-ebs-snapshot-using-aws-snapshot-lifecycle-policy-1abc0b667922

Comment: Hi AjRed, welcome to the site. It's always helpful to provide text-based explanations rather than link-only answers, as links can disappear and it might not be clear what you're referring to.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).